# Skipping unusable indexes causes dblink error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, dblink

Every once and a while when I'm executing the following statement:

```
alter session set skip_unusable_indexes=true;
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-03135: connection lost contact
ORA-02063: preceding line from my_dblink
```

---

- What does skipping indexes has to do with my dblink?
- How can I detect the problematic index?
- How can I limit the scope of the above statement only to my local indexes?

Answer (score 0):

1) What does skipping indexes has to do with my dblink?

> It has no relation. Please elaborate how you are getting the issue. Is
>   that you are login to sqlplus and as soon as you alter session, your
>   DB link disconnects?

2) How can I detect the problematic index?

```
select STATUS,index_name,table_name from user_indexes where status='UNUSABLE';

select STATUS,index_name,table_name from user_indexes where status!='VALID' and status!='N/A';
```

3) How can I limit the scope of the above statement only to my local indexes?

> I believe you meant to say the indexes on connected database and not
>   on the DB link database. You can not do this. This is session or
>   system setting.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is a bug, or at least an unimplemented feature.

When you set your session to skip unusable indexes, you're modifying the query optimiser/parser behaviour, and I suspect that this modification cannot be "pushed" to the remote instance that you have made a connection to.

I also suspect that the key to avoiding this problem, if it can be avoided, is to alter the session before referencing any database links, but even then I would not be surprised if the remote database does not implement the modification, as it is effectively a different session.